# Is the use of these words in English ever happens by English speakers?

Tags: vocabulary, spoken-english

I find it difficult to use following words while speaking english. Also no examples have been provided in internet.

Latibule(N)
Noceur
Radamancy (N)
Meraki (N)
Resfeber
Etc.

Comment: I don't recognise those as English words. Why do you want to use them?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about "words" that are completely unknown to most native Anglophones

Comment: @KateBunting I thought there would be some ways to use them, in English. These words are quite novel.

Comment: This question is hard for me to understand.  Assuming you know the meaning of these words (I don't), and you find that you don't need to use them (nor do I) then don't use them.  I know the meaning of "uvula" but in my daily life I would find it difficult to use it.  So I don't use it. If you find it difficult to use the words, then just don't use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to think I have a fairly large vocabularly, including those fashionably 'obscure' words, borrowings and neologisms that regularly do the rounds (like petrichor, hygge or sonder) - but until reading your post just now I have literally never heard or seen any of these words before.  Googling them, it appears that *noceur* is French, *meraki* is Greek, *resfeber* is Swedish, and *latibule* and *radamancy* appear to be neologisms.

Anyway, much as I don't normally like to project myself as a baseline for generalisations of hundreds of millions people worldwide, I'm fairly confident in saying these are not words any typical English speaker would ordinarily use, with the possible exception of a Buzzfeed churnalist writing an "Eleven cute loanwords from other languages you totally wish English would adopt!" piece of blogspam.  This probably explains why you are struggling to find example uses.

Comment: Thank you for "churnalist".